# What does "cast by" stand for mean the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: "(which are) cast by those with less than 15 reputation" is a reduced passive relative clause.

Comment: It's similar to: "Opinions contributed by people who have less than 15 points are kept track of."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Votes "*cast by*" simply means the *votes from* or *votes given by*, in this case, "those with less than 15 reputation". 
Possibly originates from ancient Greece - "the Ancient Greeks used pebbles to **cast their votes** – apparently depositing a small stone into one of two urns to mark their choice. After the vote had taken place, the contents of the urns were emptied and counted" http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/05/vocabulary-voting-election-etymology/